# How to prevent the animation to return to original state while inifinity times runs?

Tags: html, css, animation

I wanna make an animation that runs for infinity times but does not return to its orginal state when it completed a run. Think it like a sun moving animation. Here is a sample project

```css
.animator3{
 -webkit-animation-name:j3;
 -webkit-animation-delay:0s;
 -webkit-animation-direction:alternate;
 -webkit-animation-duration:10s;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 transform:translateX();
}
@-webkit-keyframes j3{
  0% {transform: rotate(30deg)}
  
  100% {transform: rotate(150deg)}
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.hizliresim.com/9m7y5Z.png" style="box-shadow:0 10px 20px rgb(2%,5%,5%); border-radius:50%;" width="255" height="255" id="planet" class="animator3"/>
```

It gets back to its original state once it finished each run. I dont want it. Can anyone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to run infinite times, you must set a final state that will match with the initial one.

Plus, you indicated "alternate" as animation method, so it means it would go from A to B and then from B to A and repeat.
Default option will go from A to B and then restart from A to B.

I also added `-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;` to have an animation without the acceleration and slow-down effect.

```
<style>
.animator3 {
    -webkit-animation-name:j3;
    -webkit-animation-delay:0s;
    -webkit-animation-duration:10s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    transform:translateX();
}
 @-webkit-keyframes j3{
    0% {transform: rotate(0deg)}
    100% {transform: rotate(360deg)}
}
</style>

<img src="https://i.hizliresim.com/9m7y5Z.png" style="box-shadow:0 10px 20px rgb(2%,5%,5%); border-radius:50%;" width="255" height="255" id="planet" class="animator3"/>
```

Hope it helps